# Calling hook in zustand store

Tags: reactjs, zustand

**use-language-store.tsx**

```
import { useCustomHook } from '@hooks'
import { create } from 'zustand'

type UserDataStoreProps = {
  language: string
  setLanguage: (value: string) => void
  //...
}

export const useUserDataStore = create<UserDataStore>((set) => {
  const { data } = useCustomHook()

  return {
    language: data.language,
    setLanguage: (value) => set({ language: value }),
  }
})
```

**component.tsx**

```
export const Component = () => {
  const { language } = useUserDataStore()

  return <>{language}</>
}
```

I would like to set an initial value that comes form a custom hook inside the `useUserDataStore`, however from what I understood, you can't call hooks inside zustand reducer...

How exactly should I use the store, so it can contain the initial value as imported from the `useCustomHook` so I can use it later on a different components?

Comment: I think it does not matter, it just returns data object

Comment: I'm new to Zustand but I don't think you can call hook inside of another function. In my opinion, the best way to do it is to abstract away the core logic to outside of hook so it can be used by both the hook and the `create` function.